# Ошибка при установке python3 mysqlclient

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, django, mysqlconnector

Пытаюсь установить для `django 2.0 mysqlclient`

Набираю `pip install mysqlclient` и `sudo pip install mysqlclient`.

Получаю ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-k2lwr2e2/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-k2lwr2e2/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
    libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-k2lwr2e2/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
    libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-k2lwr2e2/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
    if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
IndexError: string index out of range

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-k2lwr2e2/mysqlclient/
```

Подскажите как исправить? перечитал кучу мануалов ничего не помогло
Версия `python 3.6`
Версия `pip 9.0.1`

Использую `Django 2`, вообще его можно на `3.6 python` использовать с `mysql`?

Comment: а где вы набираете `pip install ...`??

Comment: В консоли внутри виртуального окружения.

Comment: хм. попробуйте сделать это просто в cmd

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так, благодаря комментарию lynx. Просто перезашел из виртуального окружения и сделал еще раз комманду по установке и завелось..

Answer (score 0):

У меня на Ubuntu 18.04 аналогичная проблема возникла.
Предложенный вариант не помог. Нашёл другой.

```
sudo apt install -y libmysqlclient-dev
```